# Nodetool repair validate/preview is not executed

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have 2-nodes test cluster running on Windows machines.

- Replication factor: 2
- Cassandra version: 3.10

By some reason, **nodetool repair** command with **--validate** or **--preview** flags is not executed at all, looks like parsing error. I'm not quite sure whether it's connected with Windows or I'm doing something wrong. Here's what I get for **validate** flag (similar results were received for **preview** flag):

```
C:\apache-cassandra\bin>nodetool repair --validate
nodetool: Keyspace [--validate] does not exist.

C:\apache-cassandra\bin>nodetool repair TSDB --validate
[2018-02-13 19:03:49,474] Unknown keyspace/cf pair (TSDB.--validate)
[2018-02-13 19:03:49,475] Repair command #13 finished with error
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2018-02-13 19:03:49,474] Unknown keyspace/cf pair (TSDB
.--validate)
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2018-02-13 19:03:49,474] Unknown k
eyspace/cf pair (TSDB.--validate)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.progress(RepairRunner.java:116)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.progress.jmx.JMXNotificationProgressListener.handleNotification(JMXNoti
ficationProgressListener.java:77)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.dispatchNotification(Unknown Source)

        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.doRun(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$LinearExecutor$1.run(Unknown Source)


C:\apache-cassandra\bin>nodetool repair TSDB snapshots --validate
[2018-02-13 19:04:05,185] Unknown keyspace/cf pair (TSDB.--validate)
[2018-02-13 19:04:05,186] Repair command #14 finished with error
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2018-02-13 19:04:05,185] Unknown keyspace/cf pair (TSDB
.--validate)
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2018-02-13 19:04:05,185] Unknown k
eyspace/cf pair (TSDB.--validate)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.progress(RepairRunner.java:116)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.progress.jmx.JMXNotificationProgressListener.handleNotification(JMXNoti
ficationProgressListener.java:77)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.dispatchNotification(Unknown Source)

        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.doRun(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$LinearExecutor$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas how to overcome this error and launch validation before doing repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `--validate` and `--preview` option in this version. Thats not until 4.0. The validation repair happens automatically as part of the repair you don't need to specify it. You just cant run it by itself to test the consistency yet.

Comment: thanks for so quick answer.
so there is no fast way to check the consistency in 3.x at all?

Comment: you can run the repair and look at the logs, it will report if theres differences.

Answer (score 0):

It seems nodetool repair does not support --validate or --preview options, although those are included in 3.11 official docs:
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/operating/repair.html